# How to Prove this Discrete Mathematics Argument is Valid Using Rules of Inference?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have this problem for my Assignment due tomorrow that I'm very stuck on. I need to prove the validity if the conclusion. Please help me! Thanks!

w $\lor$ $\lnot$z $\to$ r

s $\lor$ $\lnot$w

$\lnot$t

z $\to$ t

$\lnot$z $\land$ r $\to$ $\lnot$s

conclusion: $\lnot$w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From statements $3$ and $4$ and Modus Tollens we have $\lnot z$.

From $\lnot z$ and Addition, we get $w \lor \lnot z$, which by Modus Ponens in statement 1 implies $r$.

Then by Conjunction on $r$ and $\lnot z$, we have $\lnot z \land r$, which with Modus Ponens on statement $5$ gives $\lnot s$.

Then using Disjunctive Syllogism on statement $2$ and $\lnot s$, we have $\lnot w$.

If you have questions on the specific rules used, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Basic_and_derived_argument_forms, there is a big table partway down with all of them.

Comment: Thank you! but do you think you could elaborate just a bit more of the process after you get the $\lnot$z?

Comment: @BriannaDrew Sure, I'll update it